# Turn each group of multiple lines separated by empty line into one line?

Tags: linux, script

I have a file of many groups of lines, with blank line separating the "groups" of lines. I want to put each group of lines into one line separated by space.

input

```
line1
line2
line3
---blank line-
lineA
lineB
---blank line-
line$
line%
line&
line£
```

output

```
line1 line2 line3
lineA lineB
line$ line% line& line£
```

Comment: Do you have python installed on your system (type 'python' in to the CLI and if it opens, you do. To exit type: 'exit()' )

Comment: Also, can you clarify your desired output? Would it be, for a group of 3 lines and a group of two lines something which looks like: line1line2line3 line4line5 ? Or do you want all lines in a group on one line and then a newline for the next group of lines?

Comment: yes I have python, each group has different number of lines and as you understood I want all lines of the same group in one line and a new line for the next group etc.

Comment: I agree with Abraxas.  How about you show us the results of a manually-performed example, rather than try to describe the results?

Answer (score 1):

Since comments suck for formatting, please verify this is the correct input/output format desired:

InputFile.txt:

```
Iamline1
Iamline2
Iamline3
GrouponeEndswithme

Group2startshere
Thisisgroup2line2
```

OUTPUTFILE.txt:

```
Iamline1Iamline2Iamline3GrouponeEndswithme Group2startshereThisisgroup2line2
```

In this case your output file with ALL groups is still only ONE line, not multiple lines. This would also mean that ANY spaces in lines in your groups of lines would look indistinguishable from a 'new group' in the output file. If this is not your desired format PLEASE provide a sample input and ouput in your question description.

Per your description, here is a script which will create your file. Please make sure to modify the 'open('filename.txt', 'r')' with the correct filename.

```
#Line Formatter

newfile = open('newfile.txt', 'w+')

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    group = ""
    for line in f:
        if len(line) > 0:
            group += line + " "
        else:
            group = group + "\n"
            newfile.write(group)

newfile.close()
```

Per @MohsenEl-Tahawy here is his perl solution:

```
perl -00ne 's/\n/ /g;print "$_\n";' inputfile
```

Comment: thank you I have found the answer         perl -00ne 's/\n/ /g;print "$_\n";'   inputfile

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy  
Nice, I have provided a script as well. I'd recommend submitting the perl solution as an answer or marking my answer and I'll include your script as well so that future searches will find a solution. Thanks